# Save PowerPoint Slides as Images without office installed

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I need to Save PowerPoint Slides as Images in VB.NET without office installed on the PC. I have looked at the Office Interop but am not sure what I need to have installed or how to load the presentation without creating a PowerPoint Application instance?

Comment: Office Interop won't help you. It provides a way for your application to interact with PowerPoint.  For that, you need PowerPoint as well. There are products that claim to be able to manipulate PowerPoint files directly, w/o PowerPoint involved.  One I've heard about is Aspose; you might google them.

Comment: I have looked at various 3rd party products but all seem expensive considering all that I want to do is save the slides as images.

Comment: Your options are really limited to 1) Automating an instance of PowerPoint (which of course requires it to be installed), 2) use a third-party tool or 3) write your own version of PowerPoint (not a very attractive option).  It might also be possible to open some PPT files in open source apps that you can automate but if you need to be able to reproduce whatever you'd get in PPT for all possible files, I wouldn't bet on that option.